# Do express.js has variable length parameters?

Tags: node.js, express

e.g. I want to have a route like:

```
/mock/:level1/:level2/(:params)*
```

to match

```
/mock/a/b
/mock/a/b/p1
/mock/a/b/p1/p2
/mock/a/b/p1/p2/p3
```

and the value of `params` in line 4 is `p1/p2/p3`, then I can do `params.split("/")`.

EDIT:

Flask.py can do this, that exactly what I want. Does it exist in express.js?

```
@app.route('/wcfmock/<level1>/<level2>/<level3>/<path:params>')
def catch_all(level1, level2, level3, params):
    return 'You want params: %s' % params
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express handles this. From http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing :

```
 "/files/*"
 /files/jquery.js
 /files/javascripts/jquery.js
```

So, in your example, (in CoffeeScript)

```
util = require "util"

app.get '/a/b/c/*', (req, res) ->
  res.json util.inspect(req.params)
```

assuming an application structure going to port 8080...

```
http://localhost:8080/a/b/c/d/e/f
```

will return

```
"[ 'd/e/f' ]"
```