# How can I create an Express route that handles URLs that look like this?

Tags: regex, node.js, express, url-routing

```
app.get('/:service[SOMETHING GOES HERE]', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Service is:', req.params.service);
});
```

This needs to catch URLs that can look like any one of:

```
/foo
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz
```

The call back isn't concerned with anything that comes after foo, but ideally should be able to access foo as a parameter called `service` without having to manually parse the path.

I've been using [this](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/) to test and still haven't found anything that does exactly that. Closest so far is `/:service*`.

Edit: No it's not a duplicate of the one where the answer is `/:service/*` because that doesn't cover `/foo`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do express.js has variable length parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642092/do-express-js-has-variable-length-parameters)

Comment: You can't do something like this because `:service` is a variable and does not indicate where it starts or stops in the URL pattern.  So, you've provided no rule to know what part of the URL is to be interpreted as the `:service` part and which part comes after.  So, what you seem to be asking for is a route that matches everything and which you then parse pieces out of the URL after it has matched everything.  If that's not what you mean to be asking for, then please clarify your question.  Please show what you should match and what you should not match with this route.

Comment: Well to indicate where it starts and stops, express does some regex internally to match stuff between slashes. I'm just wondering if there's a simpler way to cover all cases. E.g. `/:service/:trash*` covers case 2 and 3 but not 1, and `/:service` covers 1 but not 2 and 3.

Comment: And no it's not a duplicate of the one where the answer is `/:service/*` because that doesn't cover `/foo`.

Comment: What's wrong with `/:service*`?

Comment: `/:service*` maps `service` to `foo/bar/baz` rather than `foo`.

Comment: @Paraknight not in Express itself (don't trust the tester too much ;-)

Comment: Thanks @robertklep! You're absolutely right. Care to put that in an answer so I can accept it? I'll raise an issue in the tester repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `/:service*` in actual Express routes does exactly what you want:

```
/foo           maps to { '0': '', service: 'foo' }
/foo/bar       maps to { '0': '/bar', service: 'foo' }
/foo/bar/blah  maps to { '0': '/bar/blah', service: 'foo' }
```

The [Express Route Tester](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/), for some reason, maps these URL's differently for that these kinds of patterns (it might be configured differently than Express).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [app.use()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.use) function for that. Read the doc about path handling for more info. Your code once modified will be:

```
app.use('/foo', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('Service is:', req.params.service);
});
```

The downside is that you are not going to recover `foo` as the service parameter.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear - "foo" can be anything; I don't want to do app.use for every single case, just one catch-all.

Comment: Then if "foo" can be anything then the path can be anything and app.use('/', fun...) will serve your purpose. Still you are not getting the service property. Request properties are meant to store path variables as defined in expressjs documentation. An arbitrary path is not a variable.

Comment: It's not an arbitrary path, it's just the first part of the path. The second and third are supposed to be optional - I don't care about them for this handler.